# CGImage of UIImage return NULL

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, cgimage

I created a function for splitting an image into multiple images, but when I take take the CGImage of the UIImage, the CGImage returns NULL

```
NSArray* splitImage(UIImage* image,NSUInteger pieces) {

NSLog(@"width: %f, %zu",image.size.width,CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage));
NSLog(@"%@",image.CGImage);
returns NULL
NSMutableArray* tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:pieces];

CGFloat piecesSize = image.size.height/pieces;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < pieces; i++) {

    // take in account retina displays
    CGRect subFrame = CGRectMake(0,i * piecesSize * image.scale ,image.size.width * image.scale,piecesSize * image.scale);

    CGImageRef newImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage,subFrame);

    UIImage* finalImage =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];

    CGImageRelease(newImage);

    [tempArray addObject:finalImage];

}

NSArray* finalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];

[tempArray release];

return finalArray;



}
```

Comment: check tempArray is null or not in last

Comment: CGImage is not an object, it is a C struct, so you should not be using a NSLog with %@.

Comment: The problem was that I created the UIImage with an IOSurface :D

Comment: If you want to ask a different question, please create a new, not edited here.. :)

Comment: @lnafziger: The structure is an implementation detail, with its members not visible outside of Core Graphics. CGImages are Core Foundation objects, and the documentation explicitly says that `%@` works with both Objective-C objects and Core Foundation objects. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: @PeterHosey: I didn't realize that %@ worked with CF objects.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CGImage property will return nil if the UIImage was created from another image such as an IOSurface or CIImage. To get around this in this particular case I can create a CGImage from an IOSurface using the c function then convert that to a UIImage.

```
UICreateCGImageFromIOSurface(IOSurfaceRef surface);
```

Answer (score 9):

I have created `UIImage` from `CGImage`.

```
CIImage *ciImage = image.CIImage;
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef ref = [context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:ciImage.extent];
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
```

And now `newImage.CGImage` is not `nil`

Answer (score 4):

Convert CGImage to UIImage with this and cgImage will not be null:

```
func convert(cmage:CIImage) -> UIImage
{       
    let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
    let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent)!        
    let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)        
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you did now is just create pieces with **0.f width**, you should use two `for`s to define the `width` & `height` for your pieces. Code sample like this (not tested yet, but it should works):

```
for (int height = 0; height < image.size.height; height += piecesSize) {
  for (int width = 0; width < image.size.width; width += piecesSize) {
    CGRect subFrame = CGRectMake(width, height, piecesSize, piecesSize);

    CGImageRef newImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, subFrame);
    UIImage * finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];
    CGImageRelease(newImage);

    [tempArray addObject:finalImage];
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 I have (tested) code that does this, and it matches your suggestion.  Mine is packaged as a category method on UIImage called subimageInRect:(CGRect)rect.  I think that's a prettier way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It happens in some cases when we try to crop image. I found the solution like this try this may be this can help you:-

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.9);
newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```