# Swift playground - cannot convert a filtered UIImage to a CGImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, cgimage, ciimage

In a Swift playground, I am loading a JPEG, converting it to a UIImage and filtering it to monochrome.
I then convert the resulting filtered image to a UIImage.

The input and the filtered images display correctly.

I then convert both images to a CGImage type.
This works for the input image, but the filtered image returns nil from the conversion:

```
// Get an input image
let imageFilename = "yosemite.jpg"
let inputImage = UIImage(named: imageFilename )
let inputCIImage = CIImage(image:inputImage!)

// Filter the input image - make it monochrome
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")
filter!.setDefaults()
filter!.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let CIout = filter!.outputImage
let filteredImage = UIImage(CIImage: CIout!)        

// Convert the input image to a CGImage
let inputCGImageRef = inputImage!.CGImage           // Result: <CGImage 0x7fdd095023d0>
// THE LINE ABOVE WORKS

// Try to convert the filtered image to a CGImage
let filteredCGImageRef = filteredImage.CGImage      // Result: nil
// THE LINE ABOVE DOES NOT WORK
// Note that the compiler objects to 'filteredImage!.CGImage'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022534/cgimage-of-uiimage-return-null

Comment: @BryanChen - that's the same problem, but that is an Objective C solution.

Comment: That's why I didn't close vote your question. But the link does answer you why CGImage is nil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `UIImage` created from a `CIImage` as you've done isn't backed by a `CGImage`. You need to explicitly create one:

```
let context = CIContext()
let filteredCGImageRef = context.createCGImage(
    CIout!, 
    fromRect: CIout!.extent)
```

If you need a `UIImage`, create that from the `CGImage` rendered by the `CIContext`:

```
UIImage(CGImage: filteredCGImageRef)
```

Cheers,

Simon

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I needed.

Comment: I had the exact same challenge as Simon Youens of my CIFiltered UIImage returning nil when converting it to a cgImage using .cgImage, and creating a CGImage using this explicit CIContext() method solved this for me also. Thanks greatly!