# Can CGImage created from file be null

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, cgimage

Can `image.CGImage` ever return `null` if `UIImage` was being created from file or from bundle?

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(name);
// or
UIImage image = UIImage.FromBundle(name);
// image.CGImage == null?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to @BytesGuy for help. As he said `UIImage.FromFile` and `UIImage.FromBundle` can't return `UIImage` with `null` `CGImage`.

Some correction for his answer:

> The `UIImage` can itself be `null` (and therefore `UIImage.CGImage` will also be `null`)

This is not true, if `UIImage` is `null`, `UIImage.CGImage` will throw `NullReferenceException` (will not return `null`).

Also in Xamarin.iOS it's possible to get `null` `CGImage` if `UIImage` has been disposed:

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(name);
image.Dispose();
// now image.CGImage is null
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, if the `UIImage` is not `null`, the `CGImage` will also be not `null`. There are a few cases where this is not the case ([explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035442/451678)), but this would not apply to the methods you are using.

The `UIImage` can itself be `null` (and therefore `UIImage.CGImage` will also be `null`) if the specified image could not be found - As you can see from the docs, the return will be `nil` (`null` in C#). This applies to both methods.

`FromBundle` is bound to `imageNamed:` - [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:)

`FromFile` is bound to `imageWithContentsOfFile:` - [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile:)